# Query for all properties in object field

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

this is my scenario:
I'm working on a Laravel application using [Scout Elastic Driver](https://packagist.org/packages/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver) and ElasticSearch.
I have an index that contains documents mapped like this:

```
{
   "acronym":{
      "type":"text"
   },
   "id":{
      "type":"long"
   },
   "product_id":{
      "type":"integer"
   },
   "trans":{
      "properties":{
         "en":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               }
            }
         },
         "it":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "value":{
      "type":"text"
   }
}
```

And this is my current search rule:

```
'should' =>
                [
                    [
                        'match' => [
                            'value' => $this->builder->query,
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        'match' => [
                            'trans.it' => $this->builder->query,
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'match' => [
                            'trans.en' => $this->builder->query,
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
```

It works perfectly, it returns to me data that has value in one or more of that fields correctly. But, as you can see, the trans field contains translated data and, in my application, we can have multiple translations and add everytime a new search term in query is not suitable for me.

**So, is there a way to query all properties in object field?**
Something like this:

```
[
    'match' => [
        trans.*' => $this->builder->query,
               ]
],
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
get your-index/your-type/_search
{
    "query":{
        "multi_match": {
        "query": "STRING-TO-SEARCH",
        "fields": ["trans.*"]
        }
    }
}
```